# Not able to perform base backup in postgres replication. Error: pg_basebackup: could not connect to server

Tags: postgresql, docker, database-replication, high-availability

I am running postgresql 11.2 inside docker containers.
While preparing the master and standBy PostgreSQL instances for streaming replication, I have enabled archiving on the master server. After this I need to run the `pg_basebackup` command on the standBy server to take a backup from master to standBy.
No matter what I do, I am facing the same error:

```
pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "10.244.0.1", user "repluser", SSL off
```

Commands I am running using `postgres` user, inside the docker container running standBy server, are:

```
pg_basebackup -h 10.0.0.1 -D /data/postgres -U repluser -v -P --wal-method=stream
```

OR

```
pg_basebackup -h 10.0.0.1 -U repluser -Ft -D /data/postgres
```

(Please assume 10.0.0.1 is my master server's IP and 10.0.0.2 is my standBy server's IP. They are in same subnet)

The `pg_hba.conf` file on the master server looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    replication     repluser        10.0.0.2/32             trust
```

Comment: Postgresql has told you what the problem is.  Add "10.244.0.1" to the pg_hba for replication (unless you think that that is the IP address of an MITM attacker).  Maybe you think the IP address is 10.0.0.2, but PostgreSQL does not.

Comment: 10.244.0.1 is the container network interface address on the master server itself so it never occurred to me to add this address to the pg_hba.conf. I always thought the error is coming from master's container interface that is why it says **no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "10.244.0.1"**.
Thanks a lot @jjanes

Comment: If the host machine is NATing for the virtual machine inside it, then the connection will look like it is coming from the host machine so that is what IP address you need to use.  (But of course, this means IP restriction implemented in pg_hhba doesn't provide much security, you have to implement the restriction at the host level instead, or use a different method of authentication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql has told you what the problem is. Add "10.244.0.1" to the pg_hba for replication (unless you think that that is the IP address of an MITM attacker).

Maybe you think the IP address is 10.0.0.2, but PostgreSQL does not. If the host machine is NATing the outside world for the virtual machine inside it, then the connection will look like it is coming from the host machine so that is what IP address you need to use. But of course, this means IP restriction implemented in pg_hhba doesn't provide much security since all connections might appear to come from the same place, you have to implement the restriction at the host level instead, or use a different method of authentication than just IP restriction.  You might also be able to change your VM set up so it has the network bridge rather than NAT.